# Is it possible to animate NSWindows with pop?

Tags: objective-c, animation, nswindow, facebook-pop

I want to use some of the nice looking pop animations on my application's `NSWindow`. I already do know how to animate all different kinds of CALayerBacked entities, but I can't figure out if there is a way to animate changes to the frame of my `NSWindow` for example.

The problem I'm confronted with is, that I can animate my `NSWindow`'s contentView (since it is CALayerBacked), but not the position and size of the `NSWindow` itself.

I know, that I could simply call `setFrame:display:animate:`, but this does not offer the same smooth animation as the pop framework does.

*kPOPViewFrame* is not available when using OSX. I've to use *kPOPLayerBounds* instead:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own custom properties on any object you like using:

`+ (id)propertyWithName:(NSString *)aName initializer:(void (^)(POPMutableAnimatableProperty *prop))aBlock`

You would set one up for NSWindow something like this...

```
POPAnimatableProperty *windowPositionProperty = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:@"com.myname.NSWindow.position" initializer:^(POPMutableAnimatableProperty *prop) {
    prop.readBlock = ^(NSWindow *window, CGFloat values[]) {
        values[0] = window.frame.origin.x;
        values[1] = window.frame.origin.y;
    };

    prop.writeBlock = ^(NSWindow *window, const CGFloat values[]) {
        [window setFrameOrigin:CGPointMake(values[0], values[1])];
    };
}];
```

Note the documentation comment that "Custom properties should use reverse-DNS naming."

And then setup the animation like this:

```
POPSpringAnimation *endBounce = [POPSpringAnimation animation];
endBounce.property = windowPositionProperty;
endBounce.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:targetPosition];
[window pop_addAnimation:endBounce forKey:@"endBounce"];
```

Comment: This looks like a really good idea… I’ll try it out and accept your answer, if it works.